# How does integer promotion work on C Cast?

Tags: c, types, casting, undefined-behavior, sign

I've got bitten by an unexpected integer promotion and made me wonder. ***Is it consistent across compilers whether promotion happens before explicit casting?***

Let me explain. Having a signed 8bit variable such as

`int8_t s8a = -128; //<-- 0x80`

Assigning into an unsigned 16 as `uint16_t s16b = s8a + 1;` I would expect a promotion to a larger integer `0xFF81` then assigned, this is a common mishap and is contemplated on documents like MISRA C. But explicitly casting to an unsigned type in a way like `uint16_t s16b = (uint16_t)s8a` I would have expected `s8a` to immediatly lose its "signedness" and then zero-extend to 16bit as to give `0x0080` but actually the opposite happens, as it gets sign-extended *then* lose its signedness when casted and assigned giving `0xFF80`.

Is this behavior standard or another undefined behavior of C?

Comment: This is completely intentional.  `0xFF80` can be read as -128, whereas `0x0080` is +128.  The value stays the same across the cast:  `0x80` (-128) gets converted to `0xFF80` (still -128)

Comment: A cast such as `((uint16_t)((uint8_t)s8a))` works as expected, yielding 0x0080, but the cast `(uint16_t)s8a` kinda unexpectedly yields 0xFF80 even though I'm telling C to explicitly remove the sign.

Comment: @NeonMan: Because `uint16_t` cannot represent -128, the `(uint16_t)s8a == UINT16_MAX - 128 + 1 = 0xFF80`. This behaviour is specified in C11 6.3.1.3p2.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is not related to integer promotion, but to a type conversion. In your case the process is well defined by the [C11 Standard - 6.3.1.3 Signed and unsigned integers (p2)](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.3.1.3p2):

> .. if the new type is unsigned, the value is converted by repeatedly
>   adding or subtracting one more than the maximum value that can be
>   represented in the new type until the value is in the range of the new
>   type.

So here `0xFF80 = 0xFFFF + (-128) + 1`, as `0xFFFF` is the maximum that can be represented in `uint16_t`.

Comment: A tad counter intuitive on some cases but at least is a well defined behaviour. Thank you. Edit: Will accept when SO lets me

Comment: @NeonMan: It's not really counter-intuitive if you think of (unsignedType)-n as yielding the value which, if one adds n to it and reconverts to (unsignedType), would yield zero.

Answer (score 1):

Given the initialization `int8_t s8a = -128;`:

1. In the case of the initialization `uint16_t s16b = s8a + 1;`:

   1. In the expression `s8a + 1`, the value in `s8a` (`(int8_t)-128`) is promoted to `(int)-128` and added with `(int)1` to give `(int)-127`.
   2. In the initialization `uint16_t s16b = (int)-127;`, the `(int)-127` is converted to `(uint16_t)0xff81` and stored in `s16b`.
2. In the case of the initialization `uint16_t s16b = (uint16_t)s8a + 1;`:

   1. In the expression `(uint16_t)s8a`, the value in `s8a` (`(int8_t)-128`) is converted to `(uint16_t)0xff80`.
   2. In the expression `(uint16_t)0xff80 + 1`:

      - If `INT_MAX >= 65535`, then `(uint16_t)0xff80` is converted to `(int)0xff80` and added with `(int)1` to give `(int)0xff81`.
      - If `INT_MAX < 65535`, then `1` is converted to `(uint16_t)1` and added with `(uint16_t)0xff80` to give `(uint16_t)0xff81`.
   3. In the initialization `uint16_t s16b = (int)0xff81;` (when `INT_MAX >= 65535`), or the initialization `uint16_t s16b = (uint16_t)0xff81;` (when `INT_MAX < 65535`):

      - If `INT_MAX >= 65535`, then `(int)0xff81` is converted to `(uint16_t)0xff81` and stored in `s16b`.
      - If `INT_MAX < 65535`, then `(uint16_t)0xff81` is stored in `s16b`.

In both cases `s16b` is initialized to the value `(uint16_t)0xff81`.